How to bound depth of communication with nondeterministic communication complexity and rank
In Kushilevitz and Nisan, there is an exercise which asks you to prove the following:
$D(f)=O(N^0(f)\text{log rank} (f))$.
Here, $D(f)$ is the depth of the most efficient two party communication protocol for computing $f$, $N^0(f)$ is the logarithm of the lowest number of $0$-rectangles needed to cover $f$'s matrix, and $\text{rank}(f)$ is the rank of $f$'s matrix.
If you denote $f$'s matrix as $M_f$, and the columns and rows as $X$ and $Y$ respectively, I believe being able to find a monochromatic rectangle $S\times R$ such that $M_f$ restricted $\bar{S}\times Y$ has a lower rank than $M_f$ will solve the problem, but I have been unable to prove that this is always possible.
Is anyone aware of how to solve this?
